# Can't add the same item twice to CustomProperties?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use `ActiveSheet.CustomProperties` to temporarily store my macro's settings for each worksheet. It seems impossible to add an item with the same name twice to this collection. Why?

Since each item is identified by an index number (you read a property by specifying its index number: `ActiveSheet.CustomProperties.Item(1).Name`), there is no apparent reason to be prevented from adding as much items with the same name as you want.

My code is simply:

```
ActiveSheet.CustomProperties.Add "foobar", 1
```

It works the first time, but I get the following error the second time:

> Error n° 9: Subscript out of range

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can't add it twice. You can use this code

```
Sub sample()
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.CustomProperties(1).Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    ActiveSheet.CustomProperties.Add "foobar", 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I'd like to add a property to the activesheet such as ActiveSheet.Parameter1. Is it possible to wrap the WorkSheet object in a class to extend its properties?

Comment: It is possible to have a class with a public variable declared like: "Public Withevents wb as Excel.Workbook" and then add your properties.